# SQL Server 2017 decimal rounding

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have used SQL Server 2005

SQL Server 2005 was:

```
select round(17.404800,2)
```

Result 17.40

```
select round(18.522400,2)
```

Result 18.52

but in SQL Server 2017 the results are:

```
select round(17.404800,2)
```

Result 17.400000

```
select round(18.522400,2)
```

Result 18.520000

I want to show SQL Server 2005 results ( = 17.40 / 18.52) in SQL Server 2017 - what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should cast it

like this -

```
select  cast(round(18.522400,2) as decimal(6,2))
```

Output -

```
18.52
```

Comment: its my pleasure

Answer (score 2):

Use this Query

```
select CAST (17.404800 AS decimal (6,2))
select CAST (18.522400 AS decimal (6,2))
```

And if you need to round after cast

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST (17.404800 AS decimal (18,2)), 2);
```

Comment: can you quote some cases where the above 2 results will differ?

Comment: SELECT ROUND(CAST (748.58 AS decimal (6,2)),-3); this will return 1000.00    have you got the diff?

Answer (score 0):

select cast(17.404800 as numeric(6,2));
select cast(18.522400 as numeric(6,2))